# MongoDb find using dynamic query object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I am new to node js and Mongo Db. 
I am trying to edit the user details . So for that I displayed the user list with Edit link for each user. When I click on  edit link I passed the name of the user to the router and I am successfully able to get it there. But failed to find the details of user based on that passed name.
Below is my code

```
 router.get('/edit/:name', function(req, res){
  var username= req.params['name'];
  console.log(username);
  db.collection('users').find({ name:username }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err)
            throw err;
            res.render("edit-form", {details: result})
    });
});
```

Here , when I do console.log(username); I got the username , but console.log(result); is empty. If I try to give the username directly within find method, just like below, I got the result in my page.

```
db.collection('users').find({ name:"test"}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err)
            throw err;
            res.render("edit-form", {details: result})
    });
```

How can I dynamically get the username so that I can get the corresponding user result from database.

Comment: console.log(username);  you are getting your username in log right ??

Comment: yes I am getting

Comment: what you are get   var username= req.params['name']; if you make call to edit/abc.

Comment: var username= req.params['name'];  has "test" in it. I am trying to edit the details of test, which is my user's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be problem of [deprecation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) of `req.params['name']`

You can directly get your param

```
var username= req.params.name ;
```

you need to also check you are not passing any extra space with your username.

```
 username.trim()
```

then pass it to your find

Comment: let me know if still you are not getting your data.

Comment: can you please look  into this question :     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926499/mongodb-delete-documents-by-passing-user-id

Comment: ya sure wait i'll check

Comment: not solved for this question:   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59926499/mongodb-delete-documents-by-passing-user-id