# MongoDb delete documents by passing user id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-deleteone

I am new to node and mongo db. I have a list of users with delete link in each row.I am trying to delete a user with its **_id**. However its not working.
Here is my router code.

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function (req,res) {
    const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.collection('users').deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        } else {
          return res.redirect('/'); 
        }
      });

  });
```

Here is my view, on clicking this link I am getting the _id in my url as this : **http://localhost:3000/delete/4428439e14e3343ba4ac31c1**

```
<td><a href="/delete/ <%=  userdetails._id %>">Delete</a></td>
```

***console.log(id) gives me 4428439e14e3343ba4ac31c1***

But it throws me the below error

> Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
>       at new ObjectID

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(id);` post that please

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Added a answer..

Comment: I've been update my answer, maybe it's will be work and don't forget to read my reply comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you don't need to create `ObjectID` if the string is a valid `ObjectID`

For prevention, you can use a function like below to test if valid `ObjectID` is passed or not

```
function validateObjectId (id) {
    if (ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        const obj = new ObjectId(id);
        if (obj == id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
},


if(!validateObjectId(req.params.id))
    return res.send({'error':'Invalid ObjectID Passed',id:req.params.id});

db.collection('users').deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, res) 
{
    if (err) {
    throw err;
    } else {
      return res.redirect('/'); 
    }
  });
```

Also remove extra space from here

```
<td><a href="/delete/<%=userdetails._id%>">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: it shows Invalid ObjectID Passed. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Use my updated function above & share the exact response you get

Comment: I tested it for another user and got the following response  
error "Invalid ObjectID Passed"
id " 5e2e9c65277a6f2d4881f70f"

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a instance of `ObjectId` using `new`. Currently, you are passing the ObjectId directly so you are getting that error.

```
db.collection('users').deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)},  function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Comment: @Oops try with `{_id: req.params.id}`

Comment: this one removed the error, but is not deleting the record from database.

Comment: Thank you for the code.Issue was with the extra space in my href link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this code below:

```js
router.get("/delete/:id", function(req, res) {
  const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
  var { id } = req.params;
  console.log(id);
  db.collection("users").findOneAndDelete({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, function(
    error,
    response
  ) {
    if (error) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
```

**Updated:**

Try looking at your code. There's confusing code, you use 2 times `res`. One is `res` from express and the other is`res` when it succeeds in removing at mongodb.

So, the `res.redirect ('/')` that you use in your mongodb function is `res` from mongodb, not`res` from express.

Try replacing `{err, res}` with `{error, response}`.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Same error : Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: I've been try that code above and it's working fine. Have you copied my code and tried it?

Comment: I've been try at my self and how to fix it is try to comment out your code that you think is wrong, after that save and reload your page. If you don't get an error, please open the comment and everything will return to normal. That's what I just did.

Comment: Thank you for the code.Issue was with the extra space in my href link.

Answer (score 1):

you can use findByIdAndRemove

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function (req,res) {
    var id  = req.params.id;
    db.collection('users').findByIdAndRemove( id , function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        } else {
          return res.redirect('/'); 
        }
      });

  });
```

Comment: this one gives me Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: try this out and let me know if still you get any error

Comment: It gives me : TypeError: db.collection(...).findByIdAndRemove is not a function

Comment: Thank you for the code.Issue was with the extra space in my href link